# What happens to my software when my DreamSpark account expires?

Tags: operating-system, ms-office, dreamspark

DreamSpark allows me access to a lot of useful software such as Visual Studio 2012, Office and even operating systems.

I am hesitant installing Windows 7 or even 8 on my Computer/Laptop however because I am wondering what happens once I finish University and my DreamSpark account expires? Will the OS continue to work as per usual including getting updates for it, or will I be asked to purchase a licence?

Similarly, will all my software such as Office products continue to work normally after my DreamSpark account expires, or will I get a giant message asking me to purchase the software on startup?

Thanks for any help. I had a look around the web and the only answers I could find were people saying "everything will *probably* still keep working". I'm hoping to get some real confirmation here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After going ahead and deciding to download the Software, I noticed on the lisence agreement that it mentions the Software WILL continue to work even after my DreamSpark accounts expires. The same goes with any OS I download.

Not too sure if I will continue to get updates as per usual though.

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 years of access once you open a Dreamsparks account. So get to downloading and save your copy of the program or operating system image file. The programs you download do not have an expiration. But the operating systems programs(windows 8.1,windows 7, Sever 2012 etc.) just like ones you buy at the store have only a certain amount of times you can load it on a computer. Try to limit the amount of installs you do or your product key will become invalid. So don't worry about any of the programs or OS expiring.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be usefull for somebody:
I downloaded Windows 7 in Jan 2013 just before my dreamspark account expired and I got 2 years warranty.
Right now It is almost year after warranty expired and I didn't receive any information that i should renew or buy license.
On the other hand I can't download software from dreamspark anymore or even check the windows key, but... I printed license key when I downloaded windows in 2013 (and somehow I din't lost it after almost 3 years) and now when I reinstaled Windows I didn't have any problems with installation or system activation.

Yesterday I upgraded it to Windows 10 and for now everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The software is software, it doesn't link to your subscription and doesn't have a timebomb.  It will continue to work.

You agreement, you know, the legal stuff, says you have to be a student to continue to use it.  So although the software still runs but when you signed up, you have agreed to stop using it when you are no longer a student.